# How to set timezone to the local in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, timezone

Now when I add a new record to my DB it show different time! How can I solve this problem and set timezone to the locale time?

I did try this in the `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

but it doesn't help me.

And also I did try the next:

```
def check_params
    params[:created_at] = Time.now
    permitted = params.permit(:url, :title, :description, :post_type, :category_id, :created_at)
end
```

But it doesn't help me too. What do you advice me to do?

Answer (score 0):

adding following to application.rb works

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

Comment: Why Eastern Time exactly? I want to take the local time of user

Comment: @OrkhanAlizade You might want to save the `UTC` time at database level, but while displaying time to user you can customize it according to user's local timezone. It will help you when daylight saving etc come in picture at a later point.